# Why is 308.22 + 297.93 = 606.1500000000001 and not only 606.15?

Tags: javascript

`console.log(308.22 + 297.93);`

In chrome console output is 606.1500000000001 but it should be 606.15. Why?

Comment: Long and exact response: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real numbers can not be represented in javascript (and other languages which use a floating-point type) accurately.

They are just an approximation. See [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is called rounding error - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error

It is down to how computers store floating point numbers.

That is why it is also tricky for comparisons.